# How could I change the buttonname and the variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

How could I write this in javascript or jQuery:
When I push the button the first time the `onoff` var in the `change` function gets the value `off` and the `off` button changes to a button named `on`;
 now when I press the `on` button the var `onoff` gets the value `on` and the button changes to an `off` button again.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change( inputId ) { 
        /* ... do something with inputId ... */
        var onoff = 'off';
        console.log( onoff );
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>one:</td><td><input name="one" id="one" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="b_one" value="off" onclick="change('one')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>two:</td><td><input name="two" id="two" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="b_two" value="off" onclick="change('two')"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br /><br /><input type="submit" value="ok"/></div><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in "pure" JavaScript. You will retrieve the button elements for given input and change its value based on the previous value.

```
function change( inputId ) { 
    var button = document.getElementById('b_' + inputId);
    button.value = button.value === 'off' ? 'on' : 'off';
}
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/uvavag/2/edit#html,live)** is the code.

Your `change()` function won't work because 'off' is assigned to `onoff` variable everytime the function is called. You have to move the variable definition outside the `change()` function if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's a valid use of value.  However, something like this:

```
function Change(id) {
    if( $("#"+id).val() == "on") {
        // code for on
        $("#"+id).val("off"); //switch value
    }
    else {
        // code for off
        $("#"+id).val("on"); //switch value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set event handlers without adding inline code:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
    var onoff = this.value;

    //this sets the value of the input to its current opposite
    this.value = (this.value == 'off') ? 'on' : 'off';
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/df4pu/

This also sets event handlers for every `type=button` input so you can reduce the repetitious code.

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btnOn" value="Off" />
```

Javascript

```
var status = "off"
$("#btnOn").click(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "On") {
        $(this).val("Off")
        status = "Off";
    }
    else {
        $(this).val("On")
        status = "On";
    }
    alert("status : " + status);
});
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/JCABs